# UnsatisfiedLinkError when acccessing the google calender in GWT

Tags: http, gwt

I am getting "UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.gdata.client.GData.isLoaded()" when using the gwt gdata library..

```
final String GDATA_API_KEY = "ABQIAAAABGWvCfqj7y33zGBuY57s7EfWCbD5ZXtDEt-shSPCo3EL0Dtuj-0TG3CmT93zHHI9Q";
    if (!GData.isLoaded(GDataSystemPackage.CALENDAR)) { 
        GData.loadGDataApi(GDATA_API_KEY, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {          
            authenticate();       
        }        
        }, GDataSystemPackage.CALENDAR);    
        } else {      

            authenticate(); // Load application    
        }   
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkError is a Java error that often happens if code is not available that should be - it can't happen in compiled GWT code as far as I know, since all code has to be linked at compiletime, not runtime. Are you sure you are calling that client code on a client, and not from some server code?

To clarify why this might be happening: GWT allows interaction with native JavaScript by JSNI methods - those methods look to a normal JVM like native calls, implemented with some native library, while they have a javascript impl that is used in the browser. If you try to run that code outside of a browser, there will be no way to run that JS.